# Family sharing - Ask to Buy does not offer in-person approval

Tags: ipad, family-sharing

Have just bought a new iPad (iOS 10.3.1) for my son - our first and only Apple device. Since he's only 10, have been trying to set up Family Sharing with little success.

Once logged in under his profile, he can click Ask to Buy, however on returning to my profile there is no sign of the request. A friend has suggested that there ought to be an 'approve in person' option, but one does not appear.

I don't know whether it's related, or coincidental, however:
1) content restrictions set up on his profile are applied to my profile when I log in
2) there is no ability to add apps to a wishlist (just Twitter, Facebook, Mail etc) on either of our profiles when in the App Store

Comment: Have you followed all the steps in [this Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088)?  Most problems I see on Family Sharing is that it's not setup right from the beginning.

Comment: It also sounds like you're trying to do this all on one iPad.  Family Sharing is not set up for logging in and out of the store under different appleIds on the same device.

Comment: Fab - I think so, but it's hard to tell

Comment: Tyson, thanks - not set up, or not possible? Indications from colleagues are that they can do it from one tablet, sadly they are not located near enough to help

Comment: Any further info on this?  I'm trying to setup a new iPod touch for my child and I'm also not seeing the in-person option either.  Very frustrating.  Not an apple guy and have no other apple devices in the house.

Comment: I couldn't get it working, had to resort to changing the Store password to one he didn't know and he just brings me the iPad when he wants to install something. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is make sure your device (s) are on the latest build of iOS. Make sure the app your child would like to download is in full screen (tap on it before you tap GET) Once it's full screen tap get, then Ask, (It will ask for Touch ID first if it is turned on) and at the top select Approve in person from the message displayed.